# Using regular expression, I need to match everything except for a certain date format

Tags: regex, regular-language

I've need to implement Regular Expressions as part of a project I'm working on involving OCR.

**Background**

I'm currently working on a solution where we're performing Zonal OCR on documents to capture the document date. This is fine and we can capture the date accurately. However, depending on the document contents, the "date" field may move down the document. We therefore have to set the zone to which we detect text within a column, running right down the document. This in turn will capture text we don't want/need and my only option to remove this erroneous captured text is a combination of a "Replace" function (which supports Regular Expression matching) and Regular Expression.

**Issue**

As part of the process; once we capture the text, I'll need to perform a "Replace" function, I'm specifically looking to replace all text/characters/symbols/line breaks etc apart from a certain pattern of characters. In this case:

```
\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d
```

or

```
[0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

While I can match this pattern fine, I cannot get any RegEx code to successfully match anything except the above pattern. (I'll add at this point that I'm unsure of the flavour of Regular Expression used in the product I'm working with. Documentation isn't the best :( I therefore may need to find multiple solutions to test which one works. If anyone knows of a test I can run to determine the flavour I'd appreciate it.).

The following is a sample of text captured by the OCR component:

```
"» Susi
Date of ti
31.10.2018
To preserve 
test is 31.0E
Location"
```

I want to match everything here, apart from the date "31.10.2018". I can then later use the replace function to omit everything apart from that date.

Comment: Is it possible there might be more than one date?

Comment: Hi Dan, The documents being scanned are standardsised and with the zone we're scanning, only one full date should be read.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work with this expression:

```
\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d
```

If you are going to use the date value later, you're going to want to *capture* the matching part. You can do this by putting round brackets around it, like this:

```
(\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d)
```

Now, let's try to match anything on a line, and *then* the date. "Any character" in regular expressions is `.` and any number of these is `.*`. So we now have:

```
(.*)(\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d)
```

This will match *anything* and then the date. You will find that your "anything" is captured in group 1, and the date in group 2. If it doesn't match, there is no date on the line.

The problem comes when you have more than one date on the line. By preference *anything* is a much as possible, so if there are two dates, you'll find one of them as part of the group 1 (anything) and the second in group 2. If this isn't what you want, you can put a `?` after the `*` to make it *non-greedy*, and you get this:

```
(.*?)(\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d)
```

and then, if it matches, group 2 will be the first date available, and group 1 will be the stuff on the line before it.

Lastly, you can use whichever language you are using to apply this repeatedly to a line until it doesn't match: that way each time you will get "the stuff before the date" in group 1, and the date in group 2.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thank you so much for this detailed description and answer. I'll give this a go later and keep you posted if this works.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is how I'd approach this, since there won't be another date in the document.  Might even do a `^.*(\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d).*$` which should capture the date and effectively strip the rest out.

Comment: @DanFarrell Remember that the questioner has asked for the bit that is *not* the date.